# How to set SameSite value to None in .net 4.5.2?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, session, .net-4.5

When redirected back to my site from the third party site user session becoming empty.
I have checked **Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"];** sets new value after redirect.
By default, ASP.NET_SessionId it sets as Lax.
Any possible way to change SameSite value in Session_Start of .net framework 4.5.2
or possible anywhere?

Comment: The latest same site settings are implemented in .NET Framework 4.7.2 and later: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/

Comment: @MartinCostello any possible way to handle this in 4.5,2?

Comment: Not to my knowledge no, because it's implemented in .NET Framework 4.7.2 and later.

Comment: Hi Vaibhav! My solution below was tested using 4.5.2 -- if this works for you as well, consider marking it the solution? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Couple options to work around this constraint with older versions of the .net framework

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Append("set-cookie", $"{key}={value}; path=/; SameSite=Strict; Secure");
```

Is one option for setting the headers manually with the SameSite defined. Above, key is the cookie name, value is the cookie value

Alternatively:

```
myCookie.Path = "/; SameSite=Strict; Secure";
```

I've tested these options, both appear to work

Values listed above are for examples only, you will need to supply the appropriate values [Lax|Strict|None|etc]. The Secure flag indicates that its transmitted over https only. Ymmv

Comment: sorry new to .NET.. where does the key and value come from?

Comment: Hi Dinesh, I updated the reply to clarify. The key is the cookie name, and value is cookie value (it depends on your implementation as to what these values should be)

Answer (score 1):

The trick with

```
cookie.Path = strCookiePath + "; SameSite=None";
```

doesn't work anymore (Fx 4.5.2). I searched the whole day for a solution, because we can't upgrade the Fx-Version for the site in question.

We found the following solution for the situation, where the cookie exists in the request:

```
using System.Reflection;
...
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key];
cookie.Secure = false; // Set whatever properties you need

PropertyInfo pti = cookie.GetType().GetProperty("SameSite");
if ( null != pti )
{
    pti.SetValue( cookie, -1 );  // -1 => Lax, 0 => None
}

HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add( cookie );
```

I hope it might be useful for somebody. The point here is, that the cookie was set with FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie, which doesn't set a value for SameSite. The browser turns the missing property into the "Lax" value. If you want to reset the cookie, the default value read from the request is "None". If you send the cookie without changing the SameSite-Property, the browser won't update the cookie, because the SameSite-Property of the new cookie (None) is not the same as the original (Lax).

Therefore you must change the value somehow. But since the browser sends the property to the server, the property exists and can be changed using reflection.

Comment: Tried this myself, building against 4.5.2. It *looked* like it worked locally but when deployed `pti` was null. Turns out this was a consequence of .NET upgrading in-place; although built against 4.5.2 my local machine had 4.7.2 installed so the `SameSite` property existed at runtime to set via reflection, but the deployment target was *actually* 4.5.2 and so that property *didn't* exist. I now have a hybrid approach where if the property exists at runtime it sets it, and if it doesn't it appends to the `Path` property like the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in web.config

```
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=none; Secure=true" />
      <conditions>
      </conditions>
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="No SameSite">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=none; Secure=true" negate="true" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: No joy on Safari 17 for site on .net 4.5.1
Having issues with users seemingly getting loggged out after payment via a payment processor IFrame.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the **cookieSameSite**-attribute in the **web.config** file:

```
<system.web>
    <httpCookies sameSite="None"/>
    <sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />
```

If you're using forms authentication, you can do this for the auth-cookie in the web.config file, too:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieSameSite="None" />
</authentication>
```

e.g. in SSRS:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx" name="sqlAuthCookie" timeout="3000" path="/" cookieSameSite="None">
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

If you're doing it for a System.Web.HttpCookie in code, you can abuse the cookie-path to set the same-site attribute:

```
authCookie.Path = "/; SameSite=None";
```

e.g.

```
string userName = "MY_USER";
bool createPersistentCookie = true;
string strCookiePath = "/"; 


System.Web.HttpCookie authCookie = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie, strCookiePath);


// intranet urls most of the times should not contain a dot 
// so this means if(not intranet)
// if (current.Request.Url.Host.Contains("."))
// secure can only be set when protocol is https
if ("https".Equals(current.Request.Url.Scheme, System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) 
{
    //authCookie.Path = "/; SameSite=Strict";
    authCookie.Path = strCookiePath + "; SameSite=None";
    authCookie.Secure = true;
} 

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

Comment: Not answering what OP asked for - he asked for solution in .NET 4.5.2. What you describe is for .NET 4.7.2 and above.

Comment: @dizarter: Setting it in authCookie.Path works even in .NET 4.0 and .NET 2.0. However, if e.g. ReportServer additionally sets it a second time, because it is set as default in the web.config, then that overwrites it.  That's why in the web.config, cookieSameSite="None"  needs to be set, too. However, if your framework is < cookieSameSite-Attribute, then setting the authCookie.Path alone is sufficient.